# How to find an element having random id attribute through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

How do I locate the input element by id where the last 2 numerical digits change randomly?

```
<input id="start-time-hours-c31" class="focused" name="startTimeHours" value="" placeholder="hh" maxlength="2" type="text">
```

Comment: Is `name="startTimeHours"` not unique on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Quick answer*

***When last 2 numerical digits change randomly,***

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'start-time-hours-c')]"));
```

***Using 2 attributes of Input tag,***

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='startTimeHours' and @class='focused']"));
```

***Please let us know if it resolved your query.***

Answer (score 3):

As the last 2 characters of the `id` *attribute* changes randomly, additionally you need to consider some other *attributes* as well and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id^='start-time-hours-c'][name='startTimeHours']"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'start-time-hours-c') and @name='startTimeHours']"));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As the html also has a `name` tag you can find the element by using that name tag, like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("startTimeHours"));
```

And if the `name` tag `startTimeHours` is not unique on the page, then you can find the element by using the below xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'start-time-hours')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @TheSociety answer, you can also be used as the combination of name and id

```
//input[contains(@id,'start-time-hours-c') and contains(@name,'startTimeHours')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use contains, sibling or Ancestor when the value is dynamic.

xpath - //input[contsins(@id,'start-time-hours-c')]

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of them:

```
 //input[starts-with(@id,'start-time-hours-c')]

(or)

 //input[contains(@id,'start-time-hours-c')]
```

if the above returns a single webelement then you can use it or else if it returns multiple elements go for name attribute in the xpath.